# JSF and Ajax update ui:repeat not working without loading the data from database

Tags: jsf-2

I am using Mojarra 2.3 JSF on tomcat with Weld. My problem is whenever i save a data to the database, the newest data being save doesn't show up, expert i load the data after saving it then it works. Below are my code.

```
//This is my jsf page
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="panelBlock"> 
    <ui:repeat value="#{projectBean.projectList}" var="project">
        <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{project.content}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandLink action="#{ProjectBean.save()}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="panelBlock" />
</h:commandLink>

#This is my ViewScoped

private Project project
private List<Project> projectList;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
  projectList = projectService.findAll();
}
# Setter and getter

public void save() {
   projectService.save(project)
}

#it works only after saving it i load the data from the database
public void save() {
   projectService.save(project)
   projectList = projectService.findAll();
}
```

Comment: So it works if you reaplace the database by a static arraylist? Please create an [mcve] since jsf works great/fine in this regard.

Comment: I am not using static arraylist, please check my code again. I have my jsf page and my viewscoped, what else again?

Comment: i kknow what you posted otherwise I would not have maed that comment. Good developers do 'root-cause-analysis' and exclude things. You should exclude DB being a problem. See the [mcve[ part in https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Which area of code do you want to see? I have showed the code on facelet,  the viewscoped and the version of JSF am using on tomcat with WELD. I don't get any error message. Please i need help

Answer (score -1):

You can use primefaces poll https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml for update data periodically.

Comment: Why would a `p:poll` ajax update work and an f:ajax` update fail?

Comment: may be some configuration issue or f:ajax could not find ID for re-render. Better to use primefaces, and for better re-rendering put components to primefaces output panels.

Comment: Then p:poll cannot find the id either. Ans op is not talking about periodic updates but an update after pressing a button/link